# Play part of a video in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-video

I would like to play only half of my video on a canvas but truncated on the diagonal.
At the moment I can play my full video in a canvas easyli using this little javascript:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var drawFrame = function drawFrame() {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
};

requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
```

In the end, I want to be able to play 2 videos, at the same time (I just have to call drawImage on each video), but each will be cut on diagonal, to render something like this:

[image]

I then want to move the separator depending on the mouse position.

Comment: for what purpose you wanna accomplish this, why don't you edit a video montage on some video editing software and play it on your page?  Or you are trying to create online video editor? :)

Comment: I forget a point, i want to be able to move the diagonal, depending on the mouse position. I'm upadting the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can use composition to achieve this.**

Compositions uses the alpha channel to combine non-alpha data in various way, for example "source-in" will paint source image/video where there exist pixels while "destination-over" will keep the existing pixels where there is non-alpha and only paint new ones where there is alpha (these are also known as [Porter-Duff or alpha composition](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-compositing-1-20130625/). Blending comes under the same umbrella but has a different purpose than compositing).

There are many modes but the above mentioned ones will allow us to combine them to get the part we want just by defining an alpha region that function as a mask for both. I'll include an overview to show how the operators work for each mode to better understand what they do (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing)):

[image: Comp modes]
*(A = source, B = destination)*

**The steps needed in this case would be:**

- Initialize with composition mode "`source-over`" as we use this in a loop
- Clear canvas to make sure we have an alpha channel to work with
- Draw diagonal half relative to the mouse position
- Draw video source 2 on top using "`source-in`" (to place it at the left side)
- Draw video source 1 on top using "`destination-over`"

## Working Example

This will load two different videos (links borrowed from [here](https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)) and when loaded sets up the loop as described above (just give the videos a few seconds to load):

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"), pos = c.width * 0.5, count = 2;
ctx.fillText("Please wait while videos are loading...", 20, 20);
video1.oncanplay = video2.oncanplay = function() {if (!--count) renderFrame()};

function renderFrame() {
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);     // makes sure we have an alpha channel

  ctx.beginPath();                            // draw diagonal half
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(pos - 50, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(pos + 50, c.height);
  ctx.lineTo(0, c.height);
  ctx.fill();

  // video source 2
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";        // comp in source 2
  ctx.drawImage(video2, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  
  // video source 1
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop"; // comp in source 1
  ctx.drawImage(video1, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame)
}

c.onmousemove = function(e) {
  pos = e.clientX - c.getBoundingClientRect().left;
}
```

```css
video {display:none}
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=640 height=400></canvas>
<video id=video1 muted autoplay loop src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4"></video>
<video id=video2 muted autoplay loop src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/video/movie_300.webm"></video>
```

Comment: Never heard about the composition, it's a bit tricky, even after reading the doc twice, i'm not sure to understand what happens here :D
But using this solution, I only see 1 video, and as soon as I move the mouse, there is no more video :(

Comment: @jbuiss0n oops, forgot to set initial comp. mode (source-over) for the mask. The renderFrame() must also be called each frame of course.

Comment: @jbuiss0n added actual video sources too to show it works as expected (just give the videos some time to load...)

Comment: This is awesome, thank you a lot ! I still don't fully understand how to use composition, but I will definitely look into it.

Comment: @jbuiss0n no problem. I would recommend not to get caught too much up in the math, but rather look at this graphical overview showing what each operator does with source (=new content being drawn) vs. destination (existing content) - all white in [this overview](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-compositing-1-20130625/#porterduffcompositingoperators_clear) = transparent alpha channel.

Comment: Ok I got it now, this is very usefull to known !